# Java Maze Problem - Stack Overflow Error & Maze Matrix Not Updating

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, stack-overflow, maze

I'm attempting to solve a maze problem in Java.

We have a string array. Each character in each string can be empty ("."), have an obstacle ("X"), or have a person. If it has a person, it has you ("A") or it has a stranger. A stranger can be facing east, west, up and down and their entry in the string is represented by arrows with directions. If there's a stranger in a square facing up, the corresponding character will be "^". Similarly, down is "v", left is "<" and right is ">". We want to cross through the maze without running over obstacles or being in the line of vision of a stranger (depending if they're facing up, down, left or right).

Here's what I have right now:

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    public boolean solution(String[] B) {
        //make a 2d string array 
        int numCol = B[0].length(); 
        int[][] Bcopy = new int[B.length][numCol]; 
        int rowA = -1; 
        int colA = -1; 
        for(int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<numCol; j++) {
                if(B[i].charAt(j) == 'A') {
                    rowA = i; 
                    colA = j; 
                }
                else if(B[i].charAt(j) == '>') {
                    for(int upd = j; upd<numCol; upd++){
                        Bcopy[i][upd] = -1; 
                    }
                }
                else if(B[i].charAt(j) == '<') {
                    for(int upd = 0; upd<j+1; upd++){
                        Bcopy[i][upd] = -1; 
                    }
                }
                else if(B[i].charAt(j) == 'v') {
                    for(int upd = i; upd<B.length; upd++){
                        Bcopy[upd][j] = -1; 
                    }                    
                }
                else if(B[i].charAt(j) == '^') {
                    for(int upd = 0; upd<i+1; upd++){
                        Bcopy[upd][j] = -1; 
                    }                                       
                }
                else if(B[i].charAt(j) == 'X') {
                    Bcopy[i][j] = -1; 
                }
                else if(Bcopy[i][j]==0){
                    Bcopy[i][j] = 1;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(Bcopy).replace("],", "],\n"));
        }        
        return helper(Bcopy, rowA, colA); 
    }
    public boolean helper(int[][] copy, int i, int j) {
        if(i==copy.length-1 && j==copy[0].length) {
            return true; 
        }
        if(copy[i][j]==-1) {
            return false;
        }
        if(i>=copy.length | j>=copy[0].length) {
            return false; 
        }
        return (helper(copy, i++, j)) | helper(copy, i, j++) | helper(copy, i--, j) | helper(copy, i, j--);
    }
}
```

My approach is to create an int[][] array, with `-1`'s representing where you can't go and 1 where you can go. Then it goes through all the possible paths and if it runs into something it returns but it does not update `BCopy` correctly - it only updates the arrows or the X's, but not the lines of sight of people where you can't cross.

My other issue is that I'm getting a stack overflow error.

---

I figured out why the matrix `Bcopy` wasn't changing - it didn't account for if that value had already been filled. Fixed the code for that, still stuck on the overflow error.

Comment: Stackoverflow, means the exit condition for the recursive helper function is not correct.

Comment: Look at the difference between `|` and `||`.

Comment: @tgdavies oh thanks! I updated to || so its conditional, but it still gives an overflow error.

Comment: @gvmani do you have ideas for why its not correct?

Comment: @anoncomp, sorry I dont have the exact reason. But one another possiblity is that you ar calling same function multiple times in the return. All the functions need to return before one execution is completed. So even if your code is correct it might be running out of stack.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace to your question. And update the code to the latest version.

Comment: (to me it looks as though the problem is that you don't stop the recursion when I or j are < 0, but then I'd expect and array out of bounds exception)